# Probability - Poisson arrival of rain

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to solve this Poisson problem. A rain shower lasts 10 minutes and in that time deposits $10^6$ raindrops over 100 $m^2$.

a) What is the probability of at least one drop landing in 1 $cm^2$

b)On average, how much time elapses before a raindrop hits the 1 $cm^2$ area.

I understand the first part, the intensity is 1 drop/$cm^2$ so the probability is of at least one is

$P(x\ge1)=1-\frac{(1^0)e^{-1}}{0!}=0.632$

But I'm not sure about the second part. I don't see how the number of drops, the time interval, and the two areas relate to each other to appear in a Poisson proccess. Particularly since I'm apparently not trying to find the probability of no drops after some amount of time.

Comment: The inserted values are a bit confusing. The probability is of at least one is $P(X \geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-e^{-1}\frac{1^0}{0!}\approx 0.632$ The value of x has to be 0.

Comment: Whoops, thanks. Corrected it.

Comment: It seems that you need to make some assumption on the process by which the drops fall. Presumably that would be either the completely naive idea (one falls every $t/N$ time units, where $t$ is the total time and $N$ is the number of drops), or a Poisson process. They probably intend for you to use a Poisson process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $100(100^2) = 10^6$ cm$^2$ in the full area of $100$ m$^2$.  Therefore, in $10$ minutes, an average of one raindrop fell in each cm$^2$, and the rate is $0.1$ raindrop/cm$^2$/minute.

You answer to part (a) is correct: The probability that at least one raindrop falls in any given cm$^2$ is

$$
P(X >= 1) = 1-P(0) = 1-\frac{(10 \cdot 0.1)^0}{0!}e^{-10 \cdot 0.1} = 1-e^{-1}
          \doteq 0.63212
$$

For part (b), since the rate is $\lambda = 0.1$ raindrop/cm$^2$/minute, the expected time is $1/\lambda = 10$ minutes$\cdot$cm$^2$/raindrop.  As we are concerned with only $1$ cm$^2$, the expected time is $10$ minutes/raindrop.

Comment: So there is no need to take the fact it's a Poisson process into account?

Comment: No, you do.  The mean is only $1/\lambda$ because it's Poisson.  If, for instance, raindrop interarrival time in any cm$^2$ were deterministic at $10$ minutes, then the expected time before the first raindrop would be only $5$ minutes.